# Cannot declare a parameter named 'error' when configuring karma webpack express ES6

Tags: express, webpack, babeljs, karma-webpack

I am currently trying to set up an unit test environment for a small NodeJS API I am working on.
This API is written in ES6 and it is using express to handle the requests.

The test structure I have so far is using:

- Karma
- Jasmine
- Karma-webpack
- Babel-loader

It works fine for most of my specs.

The problem is that when I try to write a spec for a Router (from Express), I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot declare a parameter named 'error' in strict mode
```

Those are the files I am using:

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        files: [{
                pattern: './src/**/*.spec.js',
                watched: false
            },
            'node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js'
        ],
        reporters: ['dots', 'growl'],
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        preprocessors: {
            './src/**/*.js': ['webpack']
        },
        webpack: {
            target: 'node',
            module: {
                loaders: [{
                    test: /\.js/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }, {
                    test: /\.json$/,
                    loader: "json-loader"
                }]
            },
            resolve: {
                extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
            },
            watch: true
        },
        webpackServer: {
            noInfo: true,
            stats: 'errors-only'
        }
    });
};
```

authRouter.js

```
import {Router} from 'express';

export class AuthRouter {
  constructor() {
    this.router = Router();
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.router.post('/login', this.login);
    this.router.get('/logout', this.logout);
  }

  login(req, res){
    //Do stuff
  }

  logout(req, res){
    // Do stuff
  }
}

const authRoutes = new AuthRouter();
authRoutes.init();

export default authRoutes.router;
```

authRouter.spec.js

```
import {AuthRouter} from './AuthRouter';

describe('AuthRouter', () => {
  let router;
  beforeEach(() => {
    router = new AuthRouter();
  });

  it('work this test :(', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true)
  });
});
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the PhantomJS is the virtual browser by javascript, not Node.js.

So run node server in the browser is not the proper way to do the test.

Maybe you can write the API test by purely mocha.

If you need the babel transform for your test code, it could be necessary.

```
mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive
```